WMI Query: how to use the LIKE operator and % with Win32_GroupUser and Win32_group.domain to substitute computer name
long time reader, first time poster here. Also, this is my first time working on a WMI query project, so forgive me if I'm a bit naive.
I'm using a 3rd party tool (Tanium) to run a WMI query on a bunch of hosts to check if the Distributed COM Users group has a user in it. This is the query I've been playing with:
SELECT PartComponent
FROM Win32_GroupUser
WHERE GroupComponent LIKE 'Win32_Group.Domain="%",Name="Distributed COM Users"'

When I test this with WBEMTEST, I get this:

Number: 0x80041017
Facility: WMI
Description: Invalid query

WMI Error: Invalid query
When I change the LIKE for = and the % for the computer's hostname, it works as expected:
SELECT PartComponent
FROM Win32_GroupUser
WHERE GroupComponent = 'Win32_Group.Domain="myhostname",Name="Distributed COM Users"'

Also, simpler queries with LIKE and % seem to be working such as this:
SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem WHERE Name LIKE '%'

Am I doing something wrong with the LIKE/%? Or is LIKE/% not supported with some part of this query?
Unfortunately, with the specific Tanium task I'm doing, I'm kinda locked down to a WMI query (I need this for the Installation Requirements/Install Verification), but if anyone has a better way of verifying, I'm all ears:) Thanks in advance for your help!

It looks valid according to the documentation. Ideally you should use Win32[_]Group because _ has special meaning, but it shouldn't cause an error.
